Connecting as another user is only supported when connecting to a computer running Windows Vista or later

Setup:

Desktop 1 - Current desktop I'm using (Windows 11)
Desktop 2 - The desktop that I want to remotely manage Task Scheduler (Windows 11 Virtual Machine)

Procedure:


Run the Task Scheduler on Desktop 1.
Right-click the "Task Scheduler (Local)"
Clicked "Connect to Another Computer..."
Selected "Another computer:" and entered the networkaddress\username of Desktop 2.
Checked the "Connect as another user: "
Clicked "Set User ..."
Input the username and the password of Desktop 2
Clicked ok.
Waited few sec. then that message appeared.

Note: 
Same message appear on physical machine (not virtual).
Remote Desktop is working on both ways.
How can I connect it?

The user(s) are both local Administrators?

@Ramhound Yes, they're both Local Administrators.
